# Summation of binomial coefficients upon $(r+2)$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> $$\sum^{50}_{r=0}(-1)^r \dfrac{\dbinom {50}r}{r+2}= ?$$

Attempt:

$(1-x)^{50}= \sum (-1)^r \dbinom{50}r x^{n-r}$

Integrating both sides and then placing limits 0 to 1:

$\dfrac{1}{51}= \displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{50}\dfrac{(-1)^r \dbinom{50}r}{52-r}$

So the answer should be $\dfrac{1}{51}$
But answer given is $1/(51\times 52)$

Where have I gone wrong?

Edit:

I understood my mistake from the comment. 
Now I have:
$\dfrac{1}{51}= \displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{50}\dfrac{(-1)^r \dbinom{50}r}{51-r}$

Is it possible to complete it *from here*?

Comment: The integral on the RHS is wrong; it gives $51-r$ in the denominators.

Comment: @Mosquite Got my mistake, What to do after that?

Comment: Now you correctly find the sum $$\sum^{50}_{r=0}(-1)^r \dfrac{\dbinom {50}r}{r+\bf{1}}.$$ But the sum in question was different.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r = 0}^{50}\pars{-1}^{r}\,{{50 \choose r} \over r + 2} & =
\sum_{r = 0}^{50}\pars{-1}^{r}\,{50 \choose r}\int_{0}^{1}t^{r + 1}\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}t\sum_{r = 0}^{50}{50 \choose r}\pars{-t}^{r}\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}t\,\pars{1 - t}^{50}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{\Gamma\pars{2}\Gamma\pars{51} \over \Gamma\pars{53}} = {1!\,50! \over 52!} =
{1 \over 52 \times 51} = \bbx{1 \over 2652}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

You have to integrate not $(1-x)^{50}$ but $x(1-x)^{50}$:
$$
(1-x)^{50}= \sum_{r\ge0} (-1)^r \dbinom{50}r x^{r}\Rightarrow\\
x(1-x)^{50}=x\sum_{r\ge0} (-1)^r\dbinom{50}r x^{r}=\sum_{r\ge0} (-1)^r\dbinom{50}r x^{r+1}\Rightarrow\\
\int_0^1 x(1-x)^{50}dx=\left[\sum_{r\ge0} (-1)^r\dbinom{50}r\frac{x^{r+2}}{r+2}\right]_0^1=\sum_{r\ge0} (-1)^r\dbinom{50}r\frac{1}{r+2}.
$$

The integral on LHS can be computed by parts:
$$
\int_0^1 x(1-x)^{50}dx=
\left[-\frac{x(1-x)^{51}}{51}\right]_0^1+\frac{1}{51}\int_0^1 (1-x)^{51}dx=\frac{1}{51\cdot52}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

> OP's expression is a special case of a formula for the *reciprocal binomial coefficient* using the *[Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)*
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\binom{n}{k}^{-1}}&\color{blue}{=(n+1)\int_0^1 z^k(1-z)^{n-k}\,dz}\\
> &=(n+1)\int_0^1z^k\sum_{r=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{r}(-z)^r\,dz\\
> &=(n+1)\sum_{r=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{r}(-1)^r\int_0^1z^{k+r}\,dz\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(n+1)\sum_{r=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{k+r+1}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We obtain from (1)
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{k+r+1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)\binom{n}{k}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> Putting $n=51$ and $k=1$ in (2) we derive OP's formula
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^{50}\binom{50}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{r+2}}=\frac{1}{52\binom{51}{1}}\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{52\cdot 51}}
> \end{align*}